# Why does $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ar}\nabla^2\nabla^2 e^{br} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{br}\nabla^2\nabla^2 e^{ar}$ for a self-adjoint operator?

Tags: spherical-coordinates, laplacian, self-adjoint-operators

If the Laplacian operator in spherical coordinates is:

$$ \nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)$$

then for $a<0$, $\int_{r=0}^\infty e^{ar}\nabla^2\nabla^2 e^{ar} (r^2 dr)$ is

$$\int_0^\infty e^{ar}\nabla^2\left[\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)e^{ar}\right] (r^2 dr)$$

$$ =\int_0^\infty \color{red}{e^{ar}\nabla^2}\left(a^2 e^{ar} + \frac{2a}{r}e^{ar} \right) (r^2 dr)$$

$$ =? \int_0^\infty\left(a^2 e^{ar} + \frac{2a}{r}e^{ar} \right) \color{red}{\nabla^2 e^{ar}} (r^2 dr)$$

$$ =\int_0^\infty\left(a^2 e^{ar} + \frac{2a}{r}e^{ar} \right)\left(a^2 e^{ar} + \frac{2a}{r}e^{ar} \right) (r^2 dr)$$

$$ =\int_0^\infty\left(a^4 e^{2ar} + \frac{4a^3}{r}e^{2ar}  + \frac{4a^2}{r^2}e^{2ar} \right) (r^2 dr)$$

$$ =\int_0^\infty\left(a^4 r^2 e^{2ar} + 4a^3re^{2ar}  + 4a^2e^{2ar} \right) dr$$

$$ =\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{a^4}{(2a)^3} \bar r^2 e^{\bar r} + \frac{4a^3}{(2a)^2}\bar r e^{\bar r}  + \frac{4a^2}{(2a)}e^{\bar r} \right) d\bar r$$

$$= -a + 2a - 2a$$

$$= -a $$

What is the concrete Hermitian/self-adjoint justification for the inversion of the operator in this equation?

Comment: The square of the Laplacian is called the Bilaplacian. To compute it in spherical coordinates, you can just compose the expression of the Laplacian in spherical coordinates with itself.

Comment: What a ugly Laplacian notation :0

Comment: @LL yes the first time i saw it twas exactly my thought, this is the general form spherical coordinate Laplacian though

Comment: @James: I think LL 3.14 was referring to the notation on the *left-hand* side. Why the hat on $\nabla$?

Comment: @HansLundmark oh... i think that's how operators are denoted in physics, with a hat, i have removed it now

Comment: Hint: if $\nabla^2=f_{ij}\partial_i\partial_j+g_i\partial_i$ then $$\begin{align}\nabla^4&=f_{ij}f_{kl}\partial_i\partial_j\partial_k\partial_l+2f_{ij}\partial_if_{kl}\partial_j\partial_k\partial_l+f_{ij}\partial_i\partial_jf_{kl}\partial_k\partial_l\\&+f_{ij}g_k\partial_i\partial_j\partial_k+2f_{ij}\partial_ig_k\partial_j\partial_k+f_{ij}\partial_i\partial_jg_k\partial_k\\&+g_if_{kl}\partial_i\partial_k\partial_l+g_i\partial_if_{kl}\partial_k\partial_l\\&+g_ig_k\partial_i\partial_k+g_i\partial_ig_k\partial_k.\end{align}$$

Comment: @J.G. thank you

Comment: It makes reading the comments slightly confusing when you edit the question and effectively ask an entire new question. Anyway: An operator like that is self-adjoint when you can do integration by parts twice (which does not change the sign) *plus* your boundary terms vanish. I don't think this is the case for $e^{ar}$ at $r=0\,.$ Haven't checked your calculations. The answer is all in integration-by-parts.

Comment: @KurtG. thank you very much.